# c#.net How can I removed duplicate rows from a DATASET

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

I need to remove the duplicate rows that contain the column names from tables inside my dataset when I write it to a CSV file. Anyone know a way I can do this?

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
Value  Value     Value
Column1 Column2 Column3 <- dont need this again
Value  Value     Value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LINQ.

```
var newtable = oldDS.Tables[0].AsEnumberable().Select(dr => dr).Distinct();

oldDS.Tables.Clear();
oldDS.Tables.Add(newtable.CopyToDataTable());
```

Comment: That was quick. Thank you Marko!

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
var distinctRows = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Distinct(DataRowComparer.Default);
var newDataTable = distinctRows.CopyToDataTable();
```

If you want to use a subset of fields only that matter for comparison you can use [morelinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) library (find on NuGet):

```
var distinctRows = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().DistinctBy(x => new
            {
                Column1= x["column1"],
                Column2 = x["column2"]
            });
```